# How to create a range of dates in an array (macro)

Tags: datetime, jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to develop a macro to create a range of dates (datetime) that will be kept in an array.
I'm a beginner with Jinja (DBT dialect) and I'm very near a solution but it seems that something is missing.
I received an error message that let me think that this is only a problem of casting.

I want to keep all code inside a macro in DBT.

Here is my code (DBT macro in Jinja) to generate the array of dates (datetime in fact) :

```
{%- macro get_range_of_dates() -%}
    {%- set dates = [] -%}
    {%- set start = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(var("currentDate"), "%Y-%m-%d") -%}
    {%- set end = modules.datetime.datetime.now() -%}

    {%- if start and end -%}
        {%- set duration = (end - start).days + 1 -%}
        {%- for day in range(0, duration) -%}
            {%- set tempo = dbt.dateadd(datepart="day", interval=day, from_date_or_timestamp="'" ~ start ~ "'") -%}
            {%- set final = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(tempo,'%Y/%m/%d') -%}
            {%- do dates.append(final) -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {{ dates }}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

When I run this code, I received the following error message:
`time data "\n\n    dateadd(\n        day,\n        0,\n        '2023-02-07 00:00:00'\n        )\n\n" does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'`

(As you can guess with this message, my variable called "CurrentDate" coming from DBT is the first date of the range and is equal to "2023-02-07").

The question: How to keep the result of "dbt.dateadd...." as a datetime in variable "tempo" ?
Do I need to cast it ? and if yes, how ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `dbt_utils` macro that already does this for you. Here's an example that uses it to build a date dimension table.

```
SELECT 
    DS.DATE_DAY RAW_DATE,
    DATE_PART('MONTH', DS.DATE_DAY) MONTH,
    DATE_PART('DAY', DS.DATE_DAY) DAY, 
    DATE_PART('YEAR', DS.DATE_DAY) YEAR,
    DATE_PART('DAYOFWEEK', DS.DATE_DAY) DAY_OF_WEEK, 
    DATE_PART('DAYOFYEAR', DS.DATE_DAY) DAY_OF_YEAR,
    DATE_PART('WEEK', DS.DATE_DAY) WEEK, 
    DATE_PART('QUARTER', DS.DATE_DAY) QUARTER,
    (DAY_OF_WEEK = 0 OR DAY_OF_WEEK = 6) IS_WEEKEND
FROM ({{ dbt_utils.date_spine(datepart="day", start_date="to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY')", end_date="to_date('12-31-2099', 'MM-DD-YYYY')" )}}) DS
```

Just replace the hardcoded dates with your `vars`.

Comment: @ Adam Kipnis: I would like to upvote your answer but I haven't enough reputation to do this so please accept my thanks in place of this upvote, regards.

Comment: @Marty_007 No problem. I just want to add a comment that in terms of best practices, I'm not sure I'd be taking the same approach you have here. Depending on how many days are in your date range, you could be generating a very inefficient SQL statement. The `date_spine` method above generates the results using a series which you can then join with instead of using one SQL statement for each date and unioning.

Comment: Make sense, thank you. I understand very well your proposition and effectively, that will make the process more "SQL" oriented than creating a long list of SELECT ...UNION. I will work at this in the next days with great enthusiasm. Thank you again for sharing these best practices and ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found myself a solution. I post it in case this can help someone.
The principal point where I was wrong was the utilization of the function "dbt.dateadd..." instead of the utilization of the function "timedelta(..." and also the fact that I didn't use directly the function "strftime" with the datetime object.

Here is the final code with comments:

```
{%- macro get_range_of_dates() -%}
{# Create an empty array to keep all dates #}
{%- set datesArray = [] -%}
{# Create a date representing the starting date of the range from a variable defined in dbt_project.yml  #}
{%- set start = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(var("currentDate"), "%Y-%m-%d") -%}
{# Create a date reprsenting the ending date of the range (always currentDay) #}
{%- set end = modules.datetime.datetime.now() -%}

{# If start and end variables are not empty...#}
{%- if start and end -%}
    {# Calculate the lenght of the range #}
    {%- set duration = (end - start).days + 1 -%}
    {# Loop the range #}
    {%- for day in range(0, duration) -%}
        {# Add one day at each iteration #}
        {%- set dateIterated = (start + modules.datetime.timedelta(day)) -%}
        {# Convert datetime to string with the desired format #}
        {%- set finalDate = dateIterated.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") -%}
        {# Append the new date to the array of dates #}
        {%- do datesArray.append(finalDate) -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%}
{# return the array of dates #}
{{ datesArray }} {%- endmacro -%}
```

Here is the call:

```
select {{ get_range_of_dates() }} from
```

And here is the results of this call:

```
select 
['2023-02-07', '2023-02-08', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-10', '2023-02-11', '2023-02-12', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-14', '2023-02-15', '2023-02-16', '2023-02-17', '2023-02-18', '2023-02-19', '2023-02-20'] from
```

Hoping that this can help somebody.
Regards.